# Restore accidentally erased /etc/group file

Tags: groups

I was trying to modify the `/etc/group` file, and accidentally cleared its contents. Now, I can't even use `sudo` anymore, and I don't know what else is broken. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Piecing together information from the Internet, I learned that the system apparently backs up some files, including `/etc/group`, to `/var/backups/[filename].bak`. Sure enough, I booted to a live USB, mounted my HD, cd'd to `/media/ubuntu/[hard drive]`, and ran:

```
sudo cp var/backups/group.bak etc/group
```

Then, when I rebooted, my system was good to go. Additionally, you can also boot the system to a root shell. (I've seen how, but I can never quite remember how.) Then, once you've mounted your rootfs as rw and all that, you'd use:

```
cp /var/backups/group.bak /etc/group
```

Another option would be to check if `/etc/group-` (note the dash) does exist. If it does you can inspect it and copy it back to `/etc/group`.

Comment: Why the hell does it want me to wait two days before I can accept my own answer? That's just stupid.

Comment: It's an auto-mechanism set for all questions in case a 'better answer comes along'. A question must be open for a few day, I assume, unless closed my a moderator.

Comment: @Rinzwind How would accepting your own answer be abused? It's not like you get rep from your own answer or anything.

Comment: This will explain it better: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer And here is the abuse I was talking about: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer#comment17369_9690 You indeed get no rep BUT you do attract upvotes for having accepted answers all over the place.

Comment: @Rinzwind I see now, that makes sense.